# Docker-compose not attach container to network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following `docker-compose.yml` with containers: `rc_db`, `rc_queue`,`rc_ui`,`rc_service`; `rc_ui` depends on `rc_db` and `rc_queue`; `rc_service` depends on `rc_queue`. All of them are located in `rc-network`. 
I've verifed that `rc_db` and `rc_queue` are located in `rc-network`, but `rc_ui` and `rc_service` still not attached @@.

It seem that it is not reach the limit of network (.i.e 1024 container?), so I don't know the reason why.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  rc_db:
    container_name: rc_db
    image: mongo:3-stretch
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME='root'
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD='1234@5678'
    command: --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
    volumes:
      - mongodbdatatest:/data/db
      - ./data/rc-db/logs:/logs
      - ./data/rc-db/mongod.conf:/etc/mongo/mongod.conf
    ports:
      - 27017
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "10"
    networks:
      - rc-network

  rc_queue:
    container_name: rc_queue
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.8-management
    restart: on-failure
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - rabbitdatatest:/var/lib/rabbitmq
      - ./data/rc-queue/logs:/var/log/rabbitmq
      - ./data/rc-queue/config:/etc/rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER='guest'
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS='guest'
      - RABBITMQ_HIPE_COMPILE=0
      - RABBITMQ_LOGS='-'
      - RABBITMQ_SASL_LOGS='-'
    expose:
      - 15671
      - 15672
      - 5672
    ports:
      - 15672
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "10"
    networks:
      - rc-network

  rc_ui:
    container_name: rc_ui
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./rc-ui.Dockerfile
    image: rc-ui
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 3005:3000
      - 3006:8080
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "30m"
        max-file: "100"
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST='rc_db'
      - MONGO_PORT=27017
      - MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME='root'
      - MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD='1234@5678'
      - AMQP_ADDRESS='rc_queue'
    volumes:
      - ./data/rc-ui/data:/data
      - ./data/rc-ui/logs:/app/logs
    depends_on:
      - rc_queue
      - rc_db
    networks:
      - rc-network

  rc_service:
    container_name: rc_service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./rc-service.Dockerfile
    image: rc-service
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./data/rc-service/config.json:/app/config.json
    ports:
      - 3001
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "10"
    depends_on:
      - rc_queue
    networks:
      - rc-network
    environment:
      - AMQP_ADDRESS='rc_queue'
volumes:
  mongodbdatatest:
  rabbitdatatest:
  mongodbdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: './data/rc-db/db'
  rabbitdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: './data/rc-queue/data'
networks:
  rc-network:
    driver: bridge
```

docker network inspect result:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "rc-builder_rc-network",
        "Id": "d7b327e45b54096c486a12147e83f546011c09f3ccbf155e30cf60834572ecbd",
        "Created": "2018-10-13T10:34:36.0643726Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.23.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "1fd09274dcd3a53b4c584d98515297852682af73493bf33dac4872058ada12de": {
                "Name": "rc_db",
                "EndpointID": "b07dff5246c5a62a2c6530247d8772d55b4ce7c733b2456bd99433bd77d9089c",
                "MacAddress": "02:41:ac:16:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "850dee45e022ec1d5d4962614c48fe0635321835e1cc7a03225c1e79330c60bf": {
                "Name": "rc_queue",
                "EndpointID": "bfc81cbc83f701d350cfafdc6e2e055b967b40198a78d834c8085e606725e9c1",
                "MacAddress": "02:41:ac:16:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "rc-network",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "rc-builder",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.22.0"
        }
    }
]
```

docker system info:

```
Containers: 5
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 81
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs
Operating System: Docker for Windows
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 2.423GiB
Name: linuxkit-00155d23e106
ID: HXSI:X5B6:673K:P4ZO:FUIM:RNAC:FXHK:UUCP:KDRE:S3YJ:L7Y4:FK2R
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 39
 Goroutines: 67
 System Time: 2018-10-13T10:42:48.0039887Z
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: You only have 2 containers running. A stopped container will not remain attached to the network.

Comment: Just because these 2 containers cannot run: they connect to `rc_db` but failed --> they're stopped.

Comment: I don't think anyone can tell you why the containers aren't running based on the details provided. See [mcve].

Comment: Thanks. It seem relate to start up order (https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/). I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about startup order. I've assumed wrong about the way to set environment variables:

They should **NOT** be:

```
environment:
  - MONGO_HOST='rc_db'
  - MONGO_PORT=27017
  - MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME='root'
  - MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD='1234@5678'
  - AMQP_ADDRESS='rc_queue'
```

but (without `'`, AMQP_ADDRESS use URL address in code so it's always `no route to host` error):

```
environment:
  - MONGO_HOST=rc_db
  - MONGO_PORT=27017
  - MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME=root
  - MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234@5678
  - AMQP_ADDRESS=rc_queue
```